# Sending and receiving SMSes in Series 40

Tags: midp, series-40

Which API can be used for sending and receiving SMSes in [Series 40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_40)?

Comment: -1, Series 40 devices are not Symbian, they only have a Java API.

Answer (score 1):

As J.N. has said, Series 40 devices are not based on Symbian OS.
For sending and receiving SMS, you'll need to use the [Wireless Messaging API](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Wireless_Messaging_API) and the [PushRegistry](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001422_-_Using_PushRegistry_in_Java_ME).